# Filtering by Strings in dataframe and adding separate values

Tags: python, pandas

given this dataframe is it possible to look for particular strings such as the countries that are located inside the countries list? (For example for the first index in 'Country', it has the word Japan inside it and its corresponding value will be 1). Is it possible to sum up the value that corresponds to each country?
(End result:
Japan: 1+3=4
USA:2
Europe:4)

```
countries=["Europe","USA","Japan"]
df=pd.DataFrame={'Employees':[1,2,3,4],
                 'Country':['Japan;Security','USA;Google',"Japan;Sega","Europe;Google"]}
print(df)
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm on mobile, but here it goes. I would make a new column with `.str.split(';')[0]` then do a `groupby` on the new column, use `.agg({'Employees':'sum'})`. This is a classic use case of `groupby`, I strongly encourage you to read the docs.

Comment: alright thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna use only those values specified in the country list. You can do something like this -

```
patt = '(' + '|'.join(countries) + ')'
grp = df.Country.str.extract(pat=patt, expand=False).values
new_df = df.groupby(grp).agg({'Employees': sum})
```

For example, if the initial country list is missing 'JAPAN' -

```
countries = ["Europe", "USA"]
patt = '(' + '|'.join(countries) + ')'
grp = df.Country.str.extract(pat=patt, expand=False).values
new_df = df.groupby(grp, dropna=False).agg({'Employees': sum}).reset_index().rename(
    columns={'index': 'Country'}).fillna('other')
```

**outptut-**

```
  Country  Employees
0  Europe          4
1     USA          2
2   other          4 # see the change
```

Comment: This is the correct and generic way of including the words in the list IMO

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
c = df['Country'].str.split(';', expand=True)[0].to_numpy()
df.groupby(c)['Employees'].sum()
```